Owl Carousel 2 - slider showing part of next image on active slide
I am using Owl Carousel 2 for my slider, but am encountering a slight bug.
At screen widths below 768px one slide is shown. Above 768px 3 slides are shown. For some reason if the screen is refreshed or if the user increases the screen width above 768px part of the 4th slide encroaches into view -

Strangely, adjusting the screen size again removes this issue but it is again present on refresh.
Here is my markup -
HTML
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/JPG_Test.jpg/154px-JPG_Test.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/JPG_Test.jpg/154px-JPG_Test.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Test-Logo.svg/783px-Test-Logo.svg.png"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/28/JPG_Test.jpg/154px-JPG_Test.jpg"></div>  
</div>

JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        nav:true,
        responsive: {
            0: { items: 1 },  // No overlap on small screens
            768: { items: 3 }
        },
    })
});

I have removed any CSS in an attempt to strip everything back to solve the issue but no luck.
Any ideas anyone?

On further investigation the issue is only present when there is no scrollbar in the browser

Hard to say without a snippet. That said, OwlCarousel2's last release was 6 years ago, and there are more than a thousand open issues on their GitHub. It wouldn't be my first choice.
